# Yii2-advanced app with SSL on localhost

Tags: apache, ssl, yii2, localhost, yii2-advanced-app

I'm running xampp on Windows. I have a yii2-advanced installation set up on an existing domain that points to my localhost by configuring the hosts file. i.e.:

hosts file:

`local.testwebsite.com 127.0.0.1`

I have to use an existing domain because I'm using some third party APIs which require the return URLs to be pointing to an online website.

Now I'm trying to create a Facebook page app, which requires the page tab to point to a HTTPS URL. http://local.testwebsite.com correctly points to my yii2 installation. However, when I try to go to https://testwebsite.com, I land at my root `htdocs` folder.

So if my Facebook page tab app is located at `controller/fb-app`, going to `http://local.testwebsite.com/controller/fb-app` will work correctly, but going to `https://local.testwebsite.com/controller/fb-app` will incorrectly try to find `../controller/app` in `htdocs`.

I realize there's some Apache configuration issue here, but I'm unsure about what to change in my apache config in order to get https to also be routing my yii2 app correctly.

Note: I don't have a certificate set up on my server. I just access it by HTTPS and bypass the browser 'unsafe' notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by configuring my yii2 `DocumentRoot` and `ServerName` in `httpd-ssl.conf` under `SSL virtual Host Context`